# Why does my kitty prefer drain water?

Tags: cats

Every morning my kitty visits one of the bathrooms to drink water from the trap in the shower area.

She has a water bowl full of fresh water every day.

She  and my cocker share the water bowl, not to mention a lot of food.

Comment: Is this early after the fresh water was filled in? Does she drink from her bowl later the day?

Comment: We change  bowl water every morning when we feed them...but she shares the bowl with our cocker, and they often steal food from each other. Should I provide another water bowl on her counter top food area?

Comment: Sometimes water from the tab holds some additives as long as in the tube, like chlorine. When coming in contact with air, this will "fly away". Animals sometimes smell or taste them, and wait for some time before drinking "fresh" water. I observed this with my rabbits. So I store some water in a can and give from there clean water into their bowl.

Comment: Interesting...we have purified water coming through a filtration system that includes UV...maybe we should start giving tap water that does not eliminate minerals...please write up this answer so I can UpVote it...your comments show much insight.

Comment: You could try to give water one day old (this is also healthy water, one day is not enough to "rot") Or you try other kinds of water, like tab water :)

Comment: When you found a solution, it would be great if yoi come back here and answer your own question for further use :)

Answer (score 2):

Cats instinctively don’t trust standing water because in nature it’s a breeding ground for disease. Running water is much safer, which is why your cat prefers drinking from the tap.

If you feed only wet food, this isn’t too bad; cats are evolved to get the water they need from their food. However, if you feed dry at all, your cat *must* drink additional water to prevent kidney failure.

The best solution is a water fountain, ideally in a place the dog can’t get into it.

Comment: She;s drinking from the _trap_...i.e. the standing water in the  soapy drain hole. She gets both wet anad dry food every day, as well as bits of meat from our meals

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine My cats lick the shower and sinks after I use them. I think they’re smart enough to understand that water is still fresh.